# Does this IVP have a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have looked at some simpler examples on ODEs, but for this problem the $e^x$ part confuses me.

> Original Problem: Does this IVP have a unique solution?
>   $$
> y' = e^x + (x/y),
> ~~~
> y(0) = 1
> $$

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), you need only to check that $e^x+x/y$ is continuous in $x$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$ for $(x,y)$ in some neighbourhood of $(0,1)$.

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method.